# How to connect to SQL Server 2005 database through Ruby

Tags: sql-server, ruby, database, sql-server-2005, connection

How to connect to SQL Server 2005 database through Ruby in Windows

Answer (score 1):

I have luck using [FreeTDS](http://freetds.schemamania.org/) and [TinyTDS](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) on Linux. I prefer that path because messing with ODBC was a pain.

In addition, I recommend using the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) ORM, because it helps remove the task of dealing with different flavors of SQL, allowing us to concentrate on programming, not writing queries that are tied to a particular DBM.

Answer (score 0):

"[Ruby, ADO, and SQLServer](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/03/ruby-ado-and-sqlserver.html)" is an example using Ruby and ADO to connect to and query an SQL Server database.

And "[Using Ruby & SQL-DMO to Automate SQL Server Tasks](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/09/using-ruby-sql-dmo-to-automate-sql.html)" demonstrates how to use Ruby and SQL-DMO to automate server tasks.