# How to connect to a MS SQL Server running in Windows from Ubuntu using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sql-server, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect to SQL Server 2005 database through Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026952/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-2005-database-through-ruby)

I have developed a database using SQL server 2008. My colleague developed the web pages and uses Ruby 1.9.3 with his local host MySQL database in Ubuntu 12.04. 
How do we connect to the MS SQL database using Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [tiny_tds](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) -- great gem by Ken Collins (@metaskills) created to talk to MS SQL

Comment: +1 Agreed. TinyTDS is a very straight path to making the connection.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using TinyTDS mentioned previously, consider using the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) ORM. It makes it easy to connect to multiple databases and abstracts the differences in their language so you can concentrate on programming, not writing queries in different flavors of SQL.